# Difference of two TimestampTypes in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Using pyspark, I have a data frame with two `TimestampType` columns:

```python
df.schema
...StructField(session_start,TimestampType,true),StructField(session_end,TimestampType,true)...
```

But I can't figure out how to compute the difference:

```python
df2 = df.withColumn("session_length",col("session_end")-col("session_start"))
```

gives me

```python
AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve '(`session_end` - `session_start`)' due to data type mismatch: '(`session_end` - `session_start`)' requires (numeric or calendarinterval) type, not timestamp ...
```

I haven't found an alternative that works.  (There's a `datediff` function, but that returns a result in days, and I need the difference in seconds.)

How should I write this?

**EDIT:** The original version of this question had a different error caused by reusing `col` as a variable in my notebook.  After redoing the `import` to get the function back, I now get the above `AnalysisException`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`pyspark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp) to convert your columns, then take the difference:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import unix_timestamp
df2 = df.withColumn(
    "session_length",
    unix_timestamp("session_end") - unix_timestamp("session_start")
)
```

Comment: Thatnks--that works.  I overlooked this because the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp) says that it takes string values.  Is a `TimestampType` really some kind of string type, or else how does it know to convert it to a string?

Comment: TBH, I'm not clear on the details but perhaps it attempts to do a conversion first. It's hard to find good documentation for pyspark functions.

Comment: How can I achieve the same in plain Spark SQL query (because I am using this in a complex case statement) rather than using function? Also I want the subtracted value as INTERVAL rather than long (in seconds) as it is coming by default.

Comment: Probably best if you post a new question with a [mcve].